# Ruby installed with RVM, but can't run .rb files

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I used RVM to install Ruby 1.9.2 successfully:

```
# rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ i386 ]

# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]
```

But I tried to run a trivial ruby script

```
Tue Aug 09 10:57:15 [root]# echo "puts \"hello\"" > test.rb
Tue Aug 09 10:57:25 [root]# ruby test.rb 
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
```

Does anyone know what's going on? Here's the output of rvm info:

```
# rvm info
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'

system:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux egkrateia 2.6.39.1-linode34 #1 SMP Tue Jun 21 10:29:24 EDT 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.2.8(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.6.32 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

  homes:
    gem:          "not set"
    ruby:         "not set"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/local/rvm/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         ":/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/Users/jku/Documents/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools:/Users/jku/Documents/android-sdk-mac_x86/platform-tools:/usr/local/rvm:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     ""
    GEM_PATH:     ""
    MY_RUBY_HOME: ""
    IRBRC:        ""
    RUBYOPT:      "-I/Users/jku/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib -rbundler/setup"
    gemset:       ""
```

Comment: Did my answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your RUBYOPT: there your loading the bundler directory and requiring it. A `gem install bundler` should be enough (or changing your RUBYOPT). If that's a rvm fresh install open an issue in rvm.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to nuke your RUBYOPT line. For the simple test script like this, you don't need the bundler gem at all.

Answer (score 0):

try

rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290

then run your ruby script.